# insert value based on input field changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following JavaScript codes in my view:

```
$('.f_opf_description_c').val(data['opf_description_c']);
$("#Form_2").on("input", function() {
   $('.f_opf_description_c').val(this.value);
});
```

I need to insert value of `data['opf_description_c']` to the field with id `Form_2`(class is `f_opf_description_c` ) when this field is not changed. If this field is changed, I need to insert  `val(this.value)`. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle or snippet?

Comment: Can you provide html code with your question?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

add some variable and change event

```
var isChange = false;
$(".f_opf_description_c").on("change", function() {
    isChange = true;
});
$("#Form_2").on("submit", function() {
 if (isChange)
   $('.f_opf_description_c').val(data['opf_description_c']);
});
```

Comment: It is not working. It is assiging data['opf_description_c'] value only

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly this fiddle can help

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var data ={'opf_description_c':'some value'};

$(".f_opf_description_c").val(data['opf_description_c']);
$("#Form_2").on("keydown", function() {
 if($(this).val() == data['opf_description_c']){
    $(this).val('')
  }
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="f_opf_description_c" id="Form_2">
</div>
```